# /usr/local/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--sysroot=/'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm unable to compile the simplest of the C programs due to some cross compilation error.
Could some shed some light on this issue.

The simplest C program ever:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf( "Hello World!\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--sysroot=/'
Try `ld --help' or `ld --usage' for more information.
collect2: error: ld returned 64 exit status
```

this is how I'm trying to compile: `gcc -o simple simple.c`

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163094

Comment: Does that mean I need to rename my /usr/local/bin/ld to somethingelse?